# How to explain gaps in Gmail user quota

Tags: gmail, google-workspace, quota

According to the Gmail storage graph available in our G Suite, there are two gaps between March 18 and April 10.

[image: Gmail storage graph]

There are no reports of malfuntion on [G Suite Status Dashboard](https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=status) during that time. Also, since this is a Free Legacy Edition account I can't ask for support to Google.

1. How could I explain such behavior?
2. Was this organization under attack?
3. How can I make sure no information was lost?

I appreciate any advice on this matter. Thank you very much.

Comment: Did you contact support about this? This might just be a rendering error in the webpage or something benign, I'd be surprised if this was malicious.

Comment: Yes Ian, I contacted support about this and because this is a Free Legacy Edition account they were not able to give further information.

Comment: For what it' worth, I checked in my account and also saw two deep dips, the same as yours, around May 27th and April 2nd.

Comment: Thanks Ian for checking in your account. I would expect to see some reports on G Suite Status Dashboard https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=status&ts=1553749199000, however there is only one report on Google Hangouts https://www.google.com/appsstatus#hl=en&v=issue&ts=1554958799000&sid=22&iid=dd99571e1e206e4aa8c75931807dfd2b but nothing about Gmail. The reason of the anomaly remains unclear to me.

Comment: I've seen minor issues before, that Google support confirmed were real issues, not reported on the dashboard. I wouldn't be surprised if it was an actual error that never made it there.